# Can Web Speech API be used in conjunction with Web Audio API?

Tags: speech, web-audio-api, speech-synthesis

Is it possible to use the synthesised speech from Web Speech API as a `SourceNode` inside Web Audio API's audio context?

Comment: It should have definitely been able to do this, but unfortunately it has not been made to do so, and still it is not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I actually asked about adding this on the Web Speech mailing list, and was basically told "no". To be fair to people on that mailing list, I was unable to think of more than one or two specific use cases when prompted.

So unless they've changed something in the past month or so, it sounds like this isn't a planned feature.

Comment: I actually wanted to use Google Chrome's V8 engine to generate Audio Files on the server. I know there are other server-side tools, to do the same, but none of them look as good as Google Chrome's TTS.

Comment: Is this still the case? I can think of quite a few examples of where it would be useful, mostly for adding effects to the speech, panning etc.

Comment: @TarwinStroh-Spijer, I had not though of that use case, but it is a great one. As for me, I wanted to do the same as Manu, simply record the output of Speech API to audio files without reverting to installing a virtual audio device application.

Comment: My use case would be implementing the https://wikivideos.org concept on the client-side, basically generating videos on the fly out of images and text, using stuff like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924613 and the synthesised speech from Web Speech API

Answer (score -4):

You can use Google's Web Speech API, you record the sound on your local machine and it is send to an external server, you can control some variants like when to stop or start the recognition and some other things. For more information here's a link:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API