# Save HTML5 Web Speech API output to file

Tags: html, google-chrome, webspeech-api

Is it possible to save Web Speech API output to a file? I'm using http://responsivevoice.org/ to create an audio snippet, however I need to maintain the same voice in platforms that do not have access to the Web Speech API.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not. It goes right to the speakers where the sound is transformed into speech voice.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the exact same thing. Although it is easily possible to use Web Speech API (via Speaker device) and at the same time record with Web Audio API (via MIC device) and save to a file. But this produces deteriorated quality (understandably so).

According to 'Kevin Ennis' from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902789/can-web-speech-api-used-in-conjunction-with-web-audio-api) answer, it was requested, but denied. Not surprised, the W3C guys aren't the brightest of the bunch when it comes to great and functional API's.

I will try to experiment with a Virtual Audio Device, such as [Virtual Audio Cable (VAC)](https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/purchase.htm) offers. This would allow to link your output (speech) directly to the input being recorded without any degradation in audio quality.

I'll be looking for an open-source/free Virtual Audio Device tool/software for Windows or Linux cause there is no way I want to pay for such a simple tool (which Microsoft should have been providing years ago).